# Tomcat6 : a way to apply a "global" accept/reject IP filter?

Tags: security, tomcat6

I've got a tomcat6 servlet container which runs various applications, such as solr. I'd like to be able to specify which IP addresses that are allowed to access the server. Is there a way to "globally", for all servlets, to specify which IP adresses that can access any of the servlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by editing the servlet context.xml file. Event though it isn't a "global" solution, it did the track and allows me to filter access by IP address.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="[IPADDRESS]"/>
</Context>
```